# Tumblr Ask Box Showing Interactions

Tags: html, css, tumblr, box

So I've been having this problem and I was hoping anyone I know can help me out with this. So far, with no luck. But [here](https://scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/11898715_398761460321618_5578232574677033785_n.jpg?oh=32773b1b07b2926ddac2f4bc74875c1a&oe=566F8597) is my Ask box on tumblr. Whenever I hover my mouse over the box, it not only wont let me type, but it shows me my interactions like it's a post. I asked my friends to check it out too, and they can't do anything on it either.

I don't know what part of my CSS/HTML is causing this problem, and how to fix it. :( It's really bothering me. And it's the same with my submission box.

My CSS/HTML is generated through [this tumblr theme generator](http://www.themesltd.com/tumblr-generator/#).
Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you Pen it? http://codepen.io/ it's really difficult to understand the problem by looking at a screenshot

Comment: when I go to my tumblr, there's a link to redirect to my ask box. And when I want to edit it, it wont redirect me to my ask box? My full code for it is [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLJROB.html)

Comment: It looks like it has to do with one of the ```:hover``` css tags. Can you do us a favor and right click your ask box in chrome/firefox and press "Inspect Element"? Then send us a screenshot. This will tell us exactly what class is effecting this.

Answer (score 0):

Find this code in the theme:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ask_form').parent().parent().children('.post-veil').remove();
        // remove the veil from ask form post
    });
</script>
```

and replace it with this:

```
$('#ask_form').parent().parent().find('.post-veil').remove();
```

You might also need to move the reference to jquery to the head of the document. At the moment it is right at the bottom.

So find near the bottom: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

And move it inside the `head` tags.

I have a version working here: http://madox-test.tumblr.com/ask

The reason is that even non blog post pages are treated as an individual 'post'. The theme already had some jquery to try and remove the veil from the ask document, but it wasn't quite selecting the right element. And/or a jquery function was being called before jquery had been loaded.